# How to test a saved file in flutter

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, file-io

This flutter web page [reading-writing-files](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files)

provides an example of saving a file, in this case containing a counter. I have pasted this into an example app. How can I unit test the file saving part of it?
My failed test attempt is below the app code.
There are 2 issues:

1. How to write the test itself - what is the testable return from the
   t = storage.writeCounter(counter);
2. how can I shut the app down and prove that the file persists and is later readable

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Reading and Writing Files',
      home: FlutterDemo(storage: CounterStorage()),
    ),
  );
}

class CounterStorage {
  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/counter.txt');
  }

  Future<int> readCounter() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;

      // Read the file
      final contents = await file.readAsString();

      return int.parse(contents);
    } catch (e) {
      // If encountering an error, return 0
      return 0;
    }
  }

  Future<File> writeCounter(int counter) async {
    final file = await _localFile;

    // Write the file
    return file.writeAsString('$counter');
  }
}

class FlutterDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const FlutterDemo({Key? key, required this.storage}) : super(key: key);

  final CounterStorage storage;

  @override
  _FlutterDemoState createState() => _FlutterDemoState();
}

class _FlutterDemoState extends State<FlutterDemo> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.storage.readCounter().then((int value) {
      setState(() {
        _counter = value;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<File> _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });

    // Write the variable as a string to the file.
    return widget.storage.writeCounter(_counter);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Reading and Writing Files'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Button tapped $_counter time${_counter == 1 ? '' : 's'}.',
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

counter_test.dart

```
import 'package:write_file_test/main.dart';

void main() {
  test('Check file save works', () async {
    final CounterStorage storage;

    var counter = 6;
    var t = storage.writeCounter(counter);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
name: write_file_test
description: Flutter test file saving

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  path_provider: ^2.0.5
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: It seems that re-starting the app can now be enabled by a dependency, so add 
  restart_app: ^1.1.0
to pubspec.yaml then add a method in main()
  // only used for testing
  void _restartApp() async {
    Restart.restartApp();
  }

Not tested yet.

Comment: I have now got a test that runs, but it still fails
void main() {
  test('Check file save works', () async {
    // Set up
    final CounterStorage storage = CounterStorage();
    final int oldCounter = await storage.readCounter();
    final int counter = oldCounter + 6;
    // Action
    await storage.writeCounter(counter);
    var result = await storage.readCounter();
    // Result - Assert
    expect(result, counter);
  });
}
It is supposed to find the current value and try and change it to a new value.